# Cobra change usage line in help template

Tags: go, command-line, go-cobra

I want to be able to set the `Usage` line to specify that an argument NEEDS to be passed if the help function is invoked on the cobra command in Go.

This is what the regular help flag outputs:

```
Cancel the order specified by the order id by submitting a cancel order.
Optionally, an account ID may be supplied as well for extra measure.

Usage:
  gbutil orders cancel [flags]

Flags:
  -a, --account_id string   the account id that the order belongs to
  -h, --help                help for cancel

Global Flags:
      --config string   config file (default is $HOME/.gbutil.yaml)
```

I want:

```
Cancel the order specified by the order id by submitting a cancel order.
Optionally, an account ID may be supplied as well for extra measure.

Usage:
  gbutil orders cancel <order_id> [flags]

Flags:
  -a, --account_id string   the account id that the order belongs to
  -h, --help                help for cancel

Global Flags:
      --config string   config file (default is $HOME/.gbutil.yaml)
```

I have tried using `SetUsageTemplate` in the `init()` function but then it deletes part of the flags:

```
orderscancelCmd.SetUsageTemplate(strings.Replace(orderscancelCmd.UsageString(), "gbutil orders cancel [flags]", "gbutil orders cancel <order_id> [flags]", 1))
```

This results in:

```
Cancel the order specified by the order id by submitting a cancel order.
Optionally, an account ID may be supplied as well for extra measure.

Usage:
  gbutil orders cancel <order_id> [flags]

Flags:
  -a, --account_id string   the account id that the order belongs to
```

where I lose the `-h` flag and the additional information about `Global Flags`.

I can get it to work if they don't provide an arg by doing:

```
        if err := cobra.ExactArgs(1)(cmd, args); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(strings.Replace(cmd.UsageString(), "gbutil orders cancel [flags]", "gbutil orders cancel <order_id> [flags]", 1))
            return
        }
```

but then the `-h` flag outputs the wrong usage line still.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change how usage name look. You can pass it in `cobra.Command.Use` parameter. So for you it probably will look like this:

```
var cmdCancel = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "cancel <order_id>",
    Args: cobra.ExactArgs(1), // make sure that only one arg can be passed
    // Your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I thought that the `Use` portion was how you called the command and couldn't be changed to include that. You also gave me some extra help with the `Args` section, which I didn't even realize!